# Parse GeoPoint Limitation

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to store locations of users using the app, but Parse is not allowing me to have two columns of GeoPoint type in one table i.e. user. I am storing 2 addresses per user.

For now, I created 4 columns (address1Longtitude, address2Longtitude, address1Latitude, address2Latitude). Any better way to do this? I will use these later to plot on Google Maps and determine route.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Only one GeoPoint column can be used with any one object. you can create a table for location and another for address 1 and address 2 and make relations with these 2 tables.
ex

```
GeoPointTable
 __________________________
|ObjectID  | geoPoint      |
|__________|_______________|
|dfj5dfs45 |1.5424,75.2425 |
|jfhd73hd7 |5.5854,25.2425 |
|gtiudfs45 |3.8924,48.1225 |

LocationsTable
 _________________________________
|ObjectID  | address1  | address2 |
|__________|___________|__________|
|dffd5ss45 |dfj5dfs45  |jfhd73hd7 |
|ljf4zf43f |jfhd73hd7  |gtiudfs45 |
```

LocationTable Refers GeopointTable

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to put the second GeoPoint (which you will not be able to index on) into a singleton array.